# Obtener valor de un atributo de un objeto en javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un objeto que tiene un atributo formados por mas atributos, algo tal que así:

```
'.texto': {
        fill: 'black',
        ref: '.body', 'ref-x': 0.5, 'x-alignment': 'middle', 'ref-y': 55, 
        'y-alignment': 'middle',
        'text-anchor': 'middle',
        'font-weight': 'bold',
        'font-variant': 'small-caps',
        'text-transform': 'capitalize',
        'font-size': '14px',
        text : ''}
```

Me gustaría saber como obtener el valor de "text" que está dentro del atributo ".texto".

Para obtener el valor de un atributo utilizo la siguiente expresión:

```
"elemento".attributes.attrs["atributo"];
```

He probado hacer algo cómo:

```
"elemento".attributes.attrs[".texto": {text}];
```

o

```
"elemento".attributes.attrs[".texto"/text}];
```

Pero no consigo obtener el valor, ¿alguien sabe como puedo obtener el valor de "text"?.

Un saludo y gracias.

Pd: Estoy utilizando las librerias jquery y joint.

Comment: Pero ¿ el elemento del que hablas es algún elemento del DOM? ¿Podrias mostrar tu HTML dónde está ese elemento ?

Comment: Si si, es un elemento del DOM, es una parte de los atributos de un objeto que he definido pero he puesto esa parte nada mas porque sólo quiero saber como acceder al valor de "text" del atributo ".texto". @A.Cedano

Comment: Deberías mostrarnos el DOM, al menos la parte donde sale ese elemento, para poder ver a que te estás refiriendo y darte los posibles caminos a ese atributo.

Answer (score 1):

```
'.texto': {
        fill: 'black',
        ref: '.body', 'ref-x': 0.5, 'x-alignment': 'middle', 'ref-y': 55, 
        'y-alignment': 'middle',
        'text-anchor': 'middle',
        'font-weight': 'bold',
        'font-variant': 'small-caps',
        'text-transform': 'capitalize',
        'font-size': '14px',
        text : ''}
```

Esto tal cual no es un objeto.
esto si:

```
var texto = {
    fill: 'black',
    ref: '.body', 'ref-x': 0.5, 'x-alignment': 'middle', 'ref-y': 55, 
    'y-alignment': 'middle',
    'text-anchor': 'middle',
    'font-weight': 'bold',
    'font-variant': 'small-caps',
    'text-transform': 'capitalize',
    'font-size': '14px',
    text : ''}
```

No se si sera un problema de concepto.
Si pones `texto.text` te saldra lo que quieres.
Espero que te sea util ;)

Answer (score 0):

Si no entendí mal, lo que quieres es algo así, ya que dices que se encuentra en el DOM:

```
$('.texto').attr('text');
```

Comment: Pero de esa forma no se escoge el atributo del elemento en seleccionado. Para coger los atributos de un objeto se escoge de la siguiente forma "elemento".attributes.attrs["atributo"];